# setRetainInstance with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

got the following example while reading android book. Can somebody please confirm to me why adapter is always created in this example? Shouldn't it be done only in the case when model == null?
If I understand correctly all data members are retained (in this example), so ListView will be retained, along with its configured ListAdapter and everything else.

```
public class AsyncDemoFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    private static final String[] items = { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor" };

    private ArrayList<String> model = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        if (model == null) {
            model = new ArrayList<String>();

            new AddStringTask().execute();
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        // …

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
            adapter.add(item[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance of your `Fragment` will be retained -- however, the `View` created by the `Fragment` will still be destroyed and recreated unless specifically retained (which can very easily cause memory leaks). Basically, without `setRetainInstance()`, the following events (along with others) would happen on a configuration change:

```
// Fragment initialized
onCreate()
onCreateView()

// Configuration change
onDestroyView()
onDestroy()
onCreate()
onCreateView()
```

With `setRetainInstance(true)`:

```
// Fragment initialized
onCreate()
onCreateView()

// Configuration change
onDestroyView()
onCreateView()
```

Essentially, you still need to recreate the `View`, but any other instance fields will not be reset.

You should still be able to handle the case where they *are* reset, however, as even with `setRetainInstance(true)` your `Activity` may be killed in the background due to memory pressure.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but just to clarify. Fragment with setRetainInstance(true) will have all its view objects destroyed or not? If yes - then the adapter instance will still be retained. Correct? so, it doesn't have to be created again if exists ( if (model == null) ). No?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put adapter = new ArrayAdapter inside the block if (model == null), so it doesn't create the new instance in cases when it exists...

Comment: Correct, you should explicitly release all view references in onDestroyView() to avoid leaking the Activity reference. In fact, I would explicitly null the adapter reference in `onDestroyView()` (since the adapter holds a strong reference to the Activity instance which is being destroyed in order to inflate item views). Keep the model around, but recreate the adapter when the View is recreated.

Comment: Now, after your explanation, I understand the idea but still not sure about the flow when I tried to run the example above earlier keeping the adapter without recreating it (inside the if block) and it worked just fine. How you would define the expected behavior in such case? Wasn't it supposed to crash?

Comment: No, it won't crash, you'll just leak memory.

Comment: So, what happens when the view is recreated and the adapter wasn't (and it holds a reference to the Activity which is being destroyed)? Is it able to inflate the new view with the old adapter  and not crash? Can you give an idea what happens in this case? thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, it'll still be able to recreate the views. It'll just be doing that with the old Activity reference that has been destroyed. Most likely nothing noticeable will happen to your app, but it would be leaking an instance of an Activity and all of its views and data until you leave the Activity altogether.